# NSOuputStream/NSInputStream Correlation

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, nsstream

What is the best way to correlation a request/response being sent/received over `NSOutputStream`/`NSInputStream`?

Essentially I am communicating with a Bluetooth device and have `NSStream`s scheduled for sending and receiving commands from the device. I would like to issue a command and wait for the response to return the result to the caller.

Is there a recommended way of doing this? The Apple demo has a generic received bytes handler but it doesn't correlate to the request that was made.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some example code? It's not clear exactly what your problem is, nor am I able to come up with an answer that's not overly broad/vague.